# perl -MCPAN Frontier

Tags: perl, debian, cpan

I have Debian 6.

I want install script PHP with perl demon. I install perl etc.

> apt-get install perl build-essential

In demon.pl I have lines:

> use Frontier::Daemon::Forking;
>
> use Crypt::XXTEA;
>
> use Cfg::Config;
>   Blockquote
>   use Unix::PasswdFile;
>
> use MIME::Base64;
>
> use File::Find;
>
> use File::Slurp;
>
> use File::Copy::Recursive qw(fcopy rcopy dircopy fmove rmove dirmove
>   pathempty pathrmdir);

I found, that I must open:

> perl -MCPAN -e shell

and install

> install Frontier::Daemon::Forking
>
> install Crypt::XXTEA
>
> install Cfg::Config
>
> install Unix::PasswdFile
>
> install MIME::Base64
>
> install File::Find
>
> install File::Slurp
>
> install File::Copy::Recursive

With all is ok without Cfg::Config, I have error:

```
    Warning: Cannot install Cfg::Config, don't know what it is.
Try the command

    i /Cfg::Config/

to find objects with matching identifiers.
CPAN: Time::HiRes loaded ok (v1.9719)
```

On end I try run demon.pl but have errors

```
./demon.pl: line 1: use: command not found
: command not found
./demon.pl: line 2: use: command not found
: command not found
./demon.pl: line 3: use: command not found
: command not found
./demon.pl: line 4: use: command not found
: command not found
./demon.pl: line 5: use: command not found
: command not found
./demon.pl: line 6: use: command not found
: command not found
./demon.pl: line 7: use: command not found
: command not found
./demon.pl: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./demon.pl: line 8: `use File::Copy::Recursive qw(fcopy rcopy dircopy fmove rmov' dirmove pathempty pathrmdir);
```

Comment: The `demon.pl` error messages come from the shell, as if `bash` is trying to interpret your Perl script. Run it as `perl demon.pl`, or make sure your script starts with a proper `#!/path/to/perl` line.

Answer (score 1):

Cfg::Config cannot be installed from CPAN because there is no such module on CPAN.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that `Cfg::Config` module is something that comes from somewhere outside of CPAN. That might be something that should come with *demon.pl*.

The other errors you see come from the shell. You're calling it like this:

```
 % ./demon.pl
```

The shell tries to execute that file as a program. It sees that it's a text file, so it looks at the first two bytes to see if they are `#!`. If so, it uses the path after `#!` as the intrepreter that will handle the text. This line is called the "shebang line". In a Perl program, it often looks something like:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
```

You only need that line if you want to make the shell figure out what to do with the file. You can specify that you want to use `perl`:

```
% perl demon.pl
```

Since you're trying to figure out if your Perl program is working and has all the modules it needs, you might try a syntax check:

```
% perl -c demon.pl
```

If you want to add the shebang line, you should find our where your `perl` is:

```
% which perl
/usr/bin/perl
```

Take that path and construct your shebang and put it at the top of your Perl program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
... # rest of program
```